# Flutter app on Chrome - no longer running - Error: The getter 'completert' isn't defined for the class 'BrowserClient'

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

This afternoon - out of the blue - my Flutter app is no longer running on Chrome

I get the following error...

```
Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...
../../sdk/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.13.5/lib/src/browser_client.dart:56:7: Error: The getter 'completert' isn't defined for the class 'BrowserClient'.
 - 'BrowserClient' is from 'package:http/src/browser_client.dart' ('../../sdk/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.13.5/lib/src/browser_client.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'completert'.
      completert.complete(StreamedResponse(
      ^^^^^^^^^^
Failed to compile application.
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

Fixed by downloading an installing the latest DART build